# How to use a multi-thread OpenGL application to update VBOs and use them at the same time?

Tags: opengl, multithreading, vbo

I have a simple application. It has two threads, each with its own rendering context, but they share one VBO (this is working, I tested it).

Now what I want: One thread is rendering some data from the first half of the VBO and the second thread is updating the second part of the VBO.

When I don't update the VBO, it's working fine.

But I have some weird issues when updating. When I use `glMapBuffer` to update the VBO (in the second thread), in the first thread, most of the time, it renders nothing—the whole screen is clear (after a `glClear` call). It looks like it can't touch data from the VBO (this is understandable, because the whole buffer is mapped and so it can be locked somehow).

I tried to use `glMapBufferRange`, which uses `GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT`. This should mean, "don't wait and use the VBO as you want, I (the program) will synchronize it by myself". Also, when I map a range of VBOs and render data from another part, it shouldn't be waiting, but I'm experiencing the same issues as I am with `glMapBuffer`.

Can anybody help me fix this or explain why it happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If someone is interested in this problem, you can find solution [on OpenGL forum](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=298438&#Post298438). Basically, buffers can't be accessed by two threads or contexts simultaneously, neither for reading nor writing. Therefore, a locking mechanism like `std::mutex` is needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the solution. I edited your answer to summarize it.